# Spring Data JPA, Hibernate, MySQL5.7.13 : cannot find entity with chinese character

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ubuntu, spring-data

I have a Spring application which fetches data from mysql 5.7.13 on local machine Ubuntu 14.04.

What doesnot work is trying to fetch an item with a condition including chinese character.

I already set my schema and tables to be utf8_default collation and InnoDB engine.

I have tried the same application under Windows and everything works well, so I just cannot understand why it stops working in Ubuntu.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")    
Item.java
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty()
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>{
    Item findByName(String name);   
}

DBConfig.java {
        @Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.domain");
    factory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
}
```

I tried to run is findByName(String name) and when I passed "toto", I got the item and when I passed "世界" it just returned null.

According to log, hibernate executes something like this:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    item0_.id as id1_4_,
    item0_.name as name2_4_,

from
    item item0_ 
where
    item0_.name=?
```

Waiting for a resolution ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it myself, but you can try to set encoding properties through url like:

?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

may be this link will be helpful:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll